# Spring JPA: Transient not working with ElementCollection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an Entity say A.

```
@Entity
class A{
 ...

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable
private List<B> bs=new ArrayList<>();

...
}

@Embeddable
class B{
 ...

@Embedded
private C c;

}

@Embeddable
class C{

  @Transient
  private String d;

 }
```

The problem i am getting  `org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing column [d] in table [B]`.

I am not sure why i am getting this error even though field is marked as transient(`javax.persistence.Transient`).

Comment: It is Embeddable.. updating question now

Comment: What columns does your Table `B` have in database? As per the exception it seems your table `B` has column `c` in it.